# How to load image from Firebase into users avatar

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, dispatch-queue

I have a problem with loading images from firebase. I have two functions. One of them collect info about user, second one load users avatar image. Unfortunately images load after function creates new user. I know it will be problem with asynchronous of Firebase but I don't know how to set up DispatchQueue to work properly. Can you help me with that?

// function that load user image in user manager class

```
func loadUserImage(contactUserID: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        var userImageRef = self.storage.child("\(userID)/userImage.jpg")
        var image = UIImage()

        if contactUserID != "" {
            userImageRef = self.storage.child("\(contactUserID)/userImage.jpg")
        }
        userImageRef.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error with retrieving data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if data?.count != 0 {
                    image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                } else {
                    image = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")!
                }
                completion(image)
            }
        }
    }
```

// function that load user in contact manager class

```
func loadContactList(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("contacts")
        .document(currentUserID)
        .collection("userContacts")
        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            var contactList = [User]()
            if let error = error {
                print("Error with retrieving data from DB: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                    for document in snapshotDocuments {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let uid = data["uid"] as! String
                        let name = data["name"] as! String
                        let email = data["email"] as! String
                        var contact = User(email: email, name: name, userID: uid)

                        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                            self.userService.loadUserImage(contactUserID: uid) { (image) in
                                contact.photoURL = image
                            }
                        }
                        contactList.append(contact)

                        contactList.sort {
                            $0.name < $1.name
                        }
                        completion(contactList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

// Function implementation in viewController

```
func loadContactList() {
    self.contactService.loadContactList { (contactArray) in
        self.contactList = contactArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to store the image url in the firebase database and after that create this extension:

```
import UIKit

let imageCache: NSCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {
    
    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {
        
        self.image = nil
        
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And call:

```
if let url = data["imgUrl"] as? String {
    self.myImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: url)
}
```

For that what you need to do is to create and initialize an `UIImage` object. If you are working with cell classes you need to create this object in the cell.